# What does 不以结婚为目的的谈恋爱都是耍流氓 mean?

Tags: word

In the first episode of the Tencent TV drama三分野, the heroine said the above sentence. What does it mean?

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Parsing? Vocabulary? Grammar?

Comment: @dROOOze I do not understand the meaning and I do not know how to categorize my problem.

Answer (score 2):

My translation:
If you date with someone while you do not have the intention to get into marriage, you are be in hoodlum.

It comes from Mao Zedong,

(who translated from "All for the purpose not to marry out of love is where bullying" by William Shakespeare. But I only find Chinese source but does not find English material)

Comment: Do you happen to know when and where Mao said that ?

Answer (score 1):

Think you are missing 一切。

一切不以结婚为目的的恋爱都是耍流氓。
All relationships which do not have marriage as their goal are immoral.

老流氓 is a common phrase. I remember asking a group of students what was their favourite season. One girl said winter. I asked why she didn't like summer. She said, "In summer we don't wear so many clothes and all the boys are 流氓。“

I saw a few references to Shakespeare, but I can't find which play this quote is supposed to come from.

老流氓：lecher, lecherous

Comment: Following your kind direction, I do some research and find that in China 耍流氓 looks like a federal felony, not merely an issue of immorality in that during the Cultural Revolution people were sentenced to death for that.

Comment: Well, I'm glad that is no longer the case! My gf calls me '老流氓‘ all the time!

Answer (score 0):

According to Dave Meurer,
`A great marriage is not when the perfect couple comes together`.

结婚为目的 means that when you fall in love, you make friend with your partner. And if and only if the relationship gets closer to become a better pair of friends.  You start to consider a marriage -- a life-long relationship with your great friend.

耍流氓的恋爱 means that when you are not perfect and you do not make a great friend with your partner.  And you know that you wouldn't propose to her and you just want to stay as the status quo.  There is no difference between this kind of 恋爱 and 耍流氓.